# Application is not starting at boot time which should do

Tags: services, startup-applications

I have a software named **something.jar**. I created a symbolic link of this software inside **/etc/init.d** with this command:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/init.d/coc/coc.jar /etc/init.d/COC
```

After this I run:

```
sudo update-rc.d COC defaults
```

So this application should start at boot time . But it doesn't.

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of file is `/etc/init.d/coc/coc.jar` ?

It seems to be a java program, which should run via a command line :

```
java -jar /Path/to/coc.jar
```

Jar files are normally not executable directly ?

Comment: Which types of files are allowed to run automatically (or as a *daemon*) ?

Comment: In fact, any "linux executable" will run as a daemon. The trick is to pack it into a script to deal with launching it (`java -jar /path/to/jar/file.jar`) and stopping it (can be as simple as `killall myjava.jar`, but may require storing PID of java execution and then kill by PID, which is wayyyyy more clean !)